# Installing Google Datalab error: No such file or directory when running Create command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Following the [installation guide](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart#before-you-begin) on the Google page, which says to run the command:

```
$ gcloud components install datalab
```

This installs the datalab commands and when I next try:

```
$ datalab create sigma2017
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Picture from console:

[image]

**EDIT2**

```
G:sdks gr$ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&access_type=offline


WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help

You are now logged in as [g*****.r*********@gmail.com].
Your current project is [*****-******-579].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
G:sdks gr$ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab create sigma2017 --verbosity=debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gr/sdks/./google-cloud-sdk/platform/datalab-cli/datalab.py", line 300, in run
    email=get_email_address(),
  File "/Users/gr/sdks/./google-cloud-sdk/platform/datalab-cli/datalab.py", line 200, in get_email_address
    'value(account)', '--filter', 'status:ACTIVE']).strip()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
G:sdks gr$
```

Comment: Can you run:
datalab create sigma2017 --verbosity=debug
to see if it gives a more informative error?

Comment: `G:~ gr$ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab create sigma2017 --verbosity=debug
-bash: ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab: No such file or directory` Seems to be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datalab command expects that the gcloud command is available in your path.  Try adding ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/ to your PATH or running from that directory.

Original Answer:

From your screenshot, it seems that get_email_account is failing.  Can you run 'gcloud auth login', which will log you in and set your account email?

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately after trying this also didn't work for me. I added another Edit for more info.

Comment: Yeah, the get_email_account thing was a red herring.  It just means that the error was during this call: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/06411c5434b6f3c07a59b1680b45bd2f9f1481dc/tools/cli/datalab.py#L300

Comment: I have a better idea of what the issue is.  I assume since you are calling it as "./google-cloud-sdk/bin/datalab" that ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/ is not in your PATH?

This means that the nested calls to 'gcloud' that the tool makes can't find your instance of gcloud, as it expects it to be in the path here: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/06411c5434b6f3c07a59b1680b45bd2f9f1481dc/tools/cli/datalab.py#L109

Try running from the ./google-cloud-sdk/bin directory, so that it can find gcloud.  (Or adding the directory to your PATH.)

Comment: Adding "./google-cloud-sdk/bin/" to the path would only work when the command is run from your home directory. A better option would be to add "~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/" to the path.

Answer (score 1):

The datalab installation seems to have failed. Please check two things below.

`$ ls ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/
$ gcloud components list`

And show the complete message that you installed the component.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot

Comment: The project and login account appear to be different. Login after running the following command. `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`